# Cannot create a folder in Data (disk /D)

Tags: directory, media

Today I tried to create folder in disk /D or folder Data...
There is folder "/media/adilbek/Data" and I can read files from it. I wanted to move somefiles between directories, so I wanted to create one more folder there. I tried shift+ctrl+N, I tried sudo mkdir, but I have the error.
"Error creating directory /media/adilbek/Data/trash/photo: No such file or directory"
"mkdir: cannot create directory ‘photo’: No such file or directory"

Any solutions? I can create folders in /home directory but not in /media.

p/s: ls -l / | grep media drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jul 4 04:13 media

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1263540/edit) and put all new information **inside the question**, not in comments and not in new answers.

Comment: Note that in Ubuntu file and folder names are case sensitive, while not so in Windows.

Comment: it will fail if trash does not exist unless you pass in -p

Comment: yeah, 'trash' exists, also i googled that mkdir -p <name> might help, but the result was the same

Comment: Grant yourself permissions to the locations where you want to be able to create and edit files and folders as an ordinary user.

Comment: @vanadium and how to do that? I tried to do that in properties->permissions but it just freezes, that`s all.

Comment: By command line: `sudo chown ...` to change owner.

Comment: the *chmod* command will change *permissions* -- *chown* changes *ownership* which is different.  With system files, I wouldn't recommend using either command unless you know exactly what you're doing and the consequences of those actions - and the ability to (remember and) revert changes if needed.